# Recommended auto-mounter for tiling window managers?

Tags: awesome, i3-wm

What is the recommended way to automatically mount usb drives, optical media, hard drives, etc... with a tiling window manager on Ubuntu?

I am a big fan of tiling window managers, but I always look like a damn fool whenever someone walks up to me with a usb key and I furiously start typing commands to create the mountpoint, figure out the name of the device in /dev, mount, etc....

I am currently using i3, but since this is a bigger issue for me than the differences between awesome/i3/dwm...

Comment: There are some other options listed on [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/277639/how-do-i-mount-a-usb-in-plain-xmonad). (I haven't tested any of them, so I'm not adding them as answers.)

Comment: I use pmount/pumount, which at least auto-creates the mount points. But you still have to know the device name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [udisks-glue](https://github.com/fernandotcl/udisks-glue) with the following configuration.  Note that this is running [Awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org) which has a [page for automounting](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Automounting) where you can find other less elegant (In my not so humble opinion) solutions...

```
 filter disks {
        optical = false
        partition_table = false
        usage = filesystem
 }
 match disks {
        automount = true
        automount_options = sync
        post_mount_command = "notify-send \"Disks-glue mount USB\" \"mounted %device_file on %mount_point\" --icon=/path/to/ikons/usb.png"
        post_unmount_command = "notify-send \"Disks-glue umount USB\" \"umounted %device_file from %mount_point\" --icon=/path/to/ikons/usb.png"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Udiskie (https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie) is the best solution for mounting disks in tiling WM